# Retrieving next N records in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, database, nosql

I need a scheduler job which will execute every 5 mins and process next 100 records from a mongodb collection. It should start from the document which was inserted first. So, in the first run, i can sort the data in ascending order and get the first 100 documents. But for the consecutive runs, how can i retrieve the next 100 records giving the last processed document's object id? (i'm not sure how to use the object id here as it is a generating string with different parameters... i don't have any other id defined.)

If this is not a good way to retrieve records from mongodb for a large data set, please suggest a better way.

Each document looks like below:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51ff17c8e4b02969f18e72bb"} , "source_of_info" : "somesource" , 
"entityinfo" : [ { "user" : "Alfredo Vela Zancada" , "social_network_entity_id" : 
 364221775325822977 , "text" : "blah blah blah" , "created_at" : { "$date" : "2013-08-
 05T03:10:12.000Z"}}] , "relatedURLs" : [ { "url" : "http://t.co/swqP3FYQt5" 
 ,"expanded_url" : "http://ow.ly/nCkIS"}]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you sorting on? What does your schema look like? Are new documents being added periodically? That would throw off your paging.

Comment: From a different scheduler, the documents will be added periodically. So i want to process the documents from the oldest one, then i don't need to worry about newly added ones. Because i will be processing next 100 documents from the oldest on every run. I planned to sort by a social network id which is always greater than exisitng documents for newly added documents. But it doesn't have a pattern, so unable to use it to fetch data. There are no paging things here, i just need to process all the records.

Comment: This question can be taken out from on hold now i guess...

Comment: You need to process in groups, or pages, of data (100). If you can't mark each document as having been processed, you'll. need at least 2 keys to sort and filter as a timestamp won't be guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've tried?

Comment: Thanks for the reply WiredPrairie. If this is a sql database, i would have taken the last processed index which i would have stored in another table and then added 100 to it to get the max limit id value and used a BETWEEN clause in my sql to get these 100 records. But i was not sure how to write such a logic with mongodb's object id as it is a complex string. Thats what i couldnt figure out. As per your suggestion, i may need to introduce another index column on the table which holds the data and handle it manually i guess.

Comment: Or I need to introduce another flag for each document and mark it as processed when done. So for each scheduler run: 1. sort 2.query by flag 3.limit(100) to retrieve the document set to be processed. Which is the better option considering performance etc?

Comment: The ObjectId only stores seconds. The remainder of the bytes are just generated to be unique and won't increase naturally, especially if you have more than one client creating them. If you look at the spec for its format, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I only have one client creating these documents, anyway, i don't think ObjectId will be useful here based on this discussion. So which one is the best solution? to have an index field or to have a flag in each document?

Comment: I'd go with the indexed field, if you can create one efficiently, accurately.

Answer (score 3):

If you keep track of which iteration you're on you could use something like:

db.users.find().limit(100).skip(1200)

Another solution might be to add a 'processed' flag to each entry. Default it to false. Then do a findAndModify when you get the next 100 where processed is false, and modify them to now be true.